# if click a div, change lat and lng of marker of google maps?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

how i can to change a position of marker when for example click on `div` ?

this is marker:

```
    var marker= new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(30,30)
      });
```

and it is show on map, but if i click a div i want that it will change the position:

```
      $('div').on('click', function(){
        var marker= new google.maps.Marker({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(60,60)
        });
      });
```

how i can do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. keep a reference to the marker rather than creating a new one on the click
2. change the position of the marker when the click event happens

```js
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(30, 30),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(30, 30),
    map: map
  });
  $('#btn').on('click', function() {
    marker.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(60, 60));
    map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
  });
  $('#btn2').on('click', function() {
    marker.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(30, 30));
    map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
#footer {
  height: 25px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="btn">click me 1</div>
<div id="btn2">click me 2</div>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```